# Change bearer token when axios.create

Tags: reactjs, axios

I create my instance axios with axios.create in my Api.js

```
import axios from 'axios';

const token = "M8uqVtkmHWAV3K2PaSZYLKkHWqeCWd22cxGNPXYnpqeT3US"

export default () => {
   let instance = axios.create({
       baseURL: process.env.REACT_APP_API_ENDPOINT,
       headers: {
           Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`
       }
   })

    instance.interceptors.request.use(request => {
        return request;
    })

    instance.interceptors.response.use( response => {
        return response.data;
    })

    return instance
}
```

How can I change the bearer token ?

I'm thinking of deleting the instance and recreating a new one with another token bearer.

Is there a better way to do it?

Comment: Its good to use interceptor to make things common like common place for Auth token, common response Handler and common error handler. 
We can handle API errors and log error in same place. So its good to use interceptors for React Axios

Comment: You can store token in local storage or http only cookie and fetch token from storage while passing in axios interceptor

Comment: Thanks @PuneetBhandari. So i can give an header as paramater to my interceptors ?

Comment: here is the response: https://gist.github.com/srph/38f67a10e991b6cb2d83 :)

Comment: correct @kan you can pass header as parameter as mentioned in above link

Answer (score 1):

We can give a header parameter in the interceptors. Thanks to Puneet Bhandari.

```
axios.interceptors.request.use(function(config) {
  const token = cookie.get(__TOKEN_KEY__);

  if ( token != null ) {
    config.headers.Authorization = `Bearer ${token}`;
  }
}
```